# Postgres - Permission denied for relation sequence

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE colors_color_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 24
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE colors_color_id_seq
  OWNER TO colors_user;
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE colors_color_id_seq TO colors_user;
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCE colors_color_id_seq TO pg_write;
```

Here is my login role:

```
CREATE ROLE scw LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT pg_connect TO scw;
GRANT pg_delete TO scw;
GRANT pg_owner TO scw;
GRANT pg_read TO scw;
GRANT pg_write TO scw;
```

And when I click on the sequence in PGAdmin III, try to insert a record into the Colors table, or `select * from colors_color_id_seq` it gives me `ERROR: Permission denied for relation colors_color_id_seq`

There are a handful of databases on the server, I can see the sequences without error in about half of them. A coworker (with seemingly the same permissions as me) can see all sequences without issue.

Is there some kind of database level permission or what else could be affecting the permissions?

Comment: Why do you do `ALTER TABLE colors_color_id_seq` in instead of `alter sequence`?

Comment: Copy/pasted from pgAdmin III when I click on the sequence, not a script I actually ran.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't see the sequence, I was relying on someone else for the above info and they were looking at a different environment that was configured correctly.

So it appears the permission was actually missing, and re-running a script that grants permissions fixed the problem.